# Filter the RSS links based on keywords in their content in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I'm creating an RSS feed with Yahoo Pipes and I'm trying to filter the links based on the keywords used in the page. How Can I do this? Note that I only have the link in the data.

An example is that I have the link : 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/11/05/microsoft-announces-major-update-to-azure-sql-database-adds-free-tier-to-azure-machine-learning.aspx

Keyword to look for in the content : "Big Data"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Fetch Page in a Loop to load the whole data and then filter it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a simple filter as in this example: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=0cdc25a071d30ef0b85331394d939c2d

The feed URL was grabbed from the feed link on the page you gave as the example.

Comment: THanks for the answer. I was trying to load the whole page completely and then filter the result with the keyword. As it appears, the fetch feed doesn't load the whole page

Comment: You typically don't want to load a whole page - site chrome, ads and all sorts of other junk litter pages? Or maybe you want to detect pages by virtue of the text around the actual content?

Comment: You are correct. What I meant was the whole post (without the junk around it) normally with Fetch Feed you would see 3-4 lines and then see "READ MORE..."

Comment: The recipe for this is to grab the feed, then for each url/link in the feed load the whole page. As per the accepted answer:-)